# TypeError: Cannot set property 'setHash' of null

Tags: angular, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

While displaying pdf file in Angular 6 using **ngx-extended-pdf-viewer**, I am getting an error in console as shown below-
[image]

html -

```
<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer src="assets/dataset/doc_2.pdf" id="idocument" type="application/pdf" width="100%"></ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
```

Tried adding delayFirstView="1000" in the properties in html but not working.

I have same confiuration as suggested on [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer) page.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `useBrowserLocale="true"` in HTML properties solved the issue.